# Deleted Old Answers

Tags: support, deleted-answers

How can one undelete an deleted answer when the answer is months old?  I have already looked at the list of deleted answers but that goes back for only a short time.

Answer (score 4):

First, look in your browser history for the answer.

If you can't find it that way either custom flag one of your other questions or answers explaining you want a moderator to find your answer, or ask a question on the site meta again asking a moderator to find your answer.

Once you've found it you can decide what to do with it. If you deleted it, you can undelete it yourself. If others deleted it, you may need to fix it first before asking a moderator to undelete it for you.

Comment: Can you or the moderator find the answer:  $B \subseteq A \cup B \subseteq B  \cup B = B$

Comment: On which site? You need to ask on the site meta and not here

Comment: Math stack exchange, elementary set theory tag.

Comment: Then you need to ask on this site and not here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/